# Retrieve table name in select statement together with other select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a query to fetch the table name in a select statement together with another select statement in SQL?

So I have table `day_table` you can find the dummy dataset here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE day_table
    (ID INT,
    day DATE)

INSERT INTO day_table (ID, day)
VALUES
  (1, 2022-01-01),
  (2, 2022-01-02),
  (3, 2022-01-03);
```

The desired output is will be like this:

```txt
day                     table_name
2022-01-01               day_table
```

I don't have any idea how to retrieve table name automatically. All I have done is manually type the name like this:

```sql
SELECT day, 'day_table' AS table_name
FROM day_table
WHERE day = '2022-01-01';
```

I don't want to manually type `SELECT **'day_table'** AS table_name`, is there another way to retrieve the currently used table name? Because I will do looping for multiple tables using shell scripting, so I have to create a "template" for every table.

Comment: And, given you know the table you are selecting from, how does having it automatically included help you?

Comment: Ok i've edited it. I want to create looping using shell script, so i need a template for every table

Comment: However you set the `FROM` part of your statement you can use to add a column for the table name.

Comment: Why did you untag MySQL?

Comment: I open for any version of sql syntax

Comment: This kind of question is going to be specific to the actual database you are using, therefore you should tag it.

Comment: If your loop can put the table name in the `from`, it can also put it in the `select`: `select day, '$table' as table_name from $table`. Also, looping in SQL is a red flag. Consider if you can rearrange the schema to avoid having to query multiple tables; perhaps ask a question about that.

Comment: The task is solvable in stored procedure format with dinamic SQL. In MySQL.

Comment: *is there other way to retrieve current use table name?* No, statement metadata is not accessible within the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Below query can help.

```
SELECT d.day,table_name 
FROM information_schema.columns, day_table d where d.day = '2022-01-01' and table_name='day_table' group by d.day
```